# How to get data from api with nodejs and sequelize

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, express, sequelize.js

I am working on a nodejs/express application with sequelize and mssql
..

I am trying to get data from an api and then save it to a database using sequelize.

I have been trying to do it with this data from a fake api using fetch but I am not able to use sequelize correctly:

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
```

This is the example I've been using as a guide

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
    console.log("First user in the array:");
    console.log(json[0]);
    console.log("Name of the first user in the array:");
    console.log(json[0].name);
 })
```

The question is:

- **How can I get this data and save it?**
- **If the request to the api needs credentials, where do I put them?**

Thanks
PS: this is my first project with nodejs and sequelize.

Comment: The question of credentials very much depends on the API. Some legacy APIs require "HTTP Basic" authentication where the username and password are concatenated with a colon `:` character, base64 encoded and sent in a HTTP header similar to `Authorization: Basic ...base64blobhere...` Most modern APIs will require "Bearer" authentication where your client first logs in to an OAuth/OAuth2 service and then supplies the `access_token` from a successful login to the data API with a header similar to `Authorization: Bearer ...access_token_here...` You'll need to consult the data API's documentation.

Comment: In this case, I think it would be the 'Bearer' thing.
I still can't fetch the fake api data so I haven't read the real api documentation.
Thanks for the information.